# preg_replace with a div and dynamic id attribute

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a div container which I wanted to delete from my coding.
The div has an id with a dynamic number.

The div look like this:

```
< div id="my-message-52617" class="label">
      all data inside this div
< /div>
```

How can I do that using `preg_replace`?

I used this:

```
preg_replace("# < div id=\"my-message- ( . * ? ) \" class=\"label\">([^`]*?) < /div>#", "", $data);
```

But it seems doesn't work at all.

I need the correct pattern to replace those data.

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML. Use an HTML parser.

Comment: I use the regex to replace some data which I don't need.
And I used HTML parser to get the data from another site... Many thanks bro... it's solve now

Answer (score 1):

It's not working... Thanks anyway bro...

I have a better solution from a friend of mine just now.
And it's working fine:

preg_replace('/< div.*?id="my-message-[\s\S]*? < /div>/i', '', '< div id="my-message-52617" class="label">all data inside this div< /div>');

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
  $data ='aaa<div id="my-message-52617" class="label"> all data inside this div</div><div>This should not be deleted.</div>';
  echo preg_replace('#<div id="my-message-(.)*" class="label">[a-zA-Z0-9\s\.]*</div>#','',$data);
```